# Parameter derivative of hypergeometric function with negative half-integer parameters

Tags: derivatives, hypergeometric-function

I am dealing with an expression containing up to third derivatives with respect to the parameters of the hypergeometric function of the form

$_2F_1(\{-\frac{n_1}{2},\frac{1}{2}-\frac{n_1}{2}\},\{1-2 n_2\},x)$

where $n_1$ and $n_2$ are non-negative integers. The first of these for $n_1\le 3$ and $n_2=0$ can all be evaluated using the HypExp2 package and Mathematica 12 in terms of logarithms and PolyGamma functions. But as soon as $n_1\ge 4$ or $n_2\ne 0$ examples appear that fail to be evaluated. For example the derivative

$_2F^{((2,0),(1),0)}_1(\{-2,-\frac{3}{2}\},\{-1\},x)$

takes a long time to evaluate and in the end produces internal variables of the HypExp2 package which do not cancel out. Mathematica 12 without the package does not even give numerical values unless x=0. Is there a way to evaluate derivatives of this type in closed form?

Comment: ${_2 F_1}(a, b; -1; x)$ is undefined though.

Comment: Can you give me a source why derivatives of this function are undefined? I find for example for the derivative $ _2F_1^{0,1,1,0}(1,1;-1,z)=\frac{4 z^2 \text{Li}_2(z)}{(z-1)^3}+\frac{4 z^2 \text{Li}_3(1-z)}{(z-1)^3}+\frac{2 z^2 \text{Li}_3(z)}{(z-1)^3}-\frac{4 z^2 \zeta (3)}{(z-1)^3}-\frac{z^2 \log ^3(1-z)}{(z-1)^3}+\frac{5 z^2 \log ^2(1-z)}{2 (z-1)^3}+\frac{2 z^2 \log (z) \log
   ^2(1-z)}{(z-1)^3}-\frac{2 \pi ^2 z^2 \log (1-z)}{3 (z-1)^3}+\frac{z^2 \log (1-z)}{(z-1)^3}+\frac{z}{(z-1)^3}$

Comment: With the package loaded, `D[Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1, c, x], c] /. c -> -1` gives the coefficient at $(c + 1)^1$ in the Laurent expansion around $c = -1$. Is this meaningful for your application? ${_2 F_1}(1, 1; c; x)$ has a pole at $c = -1$ because of $(c)_k$ in the denominator in the hypergeometric series.

Comment: Yes indeed, these coefficients enter the expressions for periods of Calabi-Yau manifolds. All singularities cancel in the final expressions, such that there is a pole in the original function is not problematic.